# Operations on arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numbers

I have a simple question. For example, how can I get the odd numbers in a= ['p','y','t','h','o','n'] array. output to me: It should be ['y','h','n']. Thank you.

Comment: There is no odd number in `a`. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: So you want something like `print(['p','y','t','h','o','n'][1::2])`?

Comment: you can use the slice notation to get it. [understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1):

you can use slicing :

```
output = a[1::2]
```

Comment: that's what i was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`a = ['p','y','t','h','o','n']`

only consider a character where the index is odd

`b = [item for idx, item in enumerate(a) if idx % 2 != 0]`

`print(b) // ['y', 'h', 'n']`